# Create array from one textbox and send to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, textbox

I need to send an array generated in an HTML form to a PHP script. I know how to perform the procedure when the array is ready, but my problem is this: the array must be generated from the contents of a textbox, dynamically.

The user types a value in the textbox, and clicks the "append" button, and then the value is added to an array. Then, the user types another value in the same textbox, clicks the button, and the value is inserted into the array, and so on.
At the end, it clicks the submit button, and the entire array is sent to the server to be processed by a PHP script.

This is the code I used:

```
<input type = "text" name = "color[]" id = "color" size = "50" placeholder 
= "Type a color here" /> <br>
<button type = "button" onclick = "append()">Add color </ button>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Send" /> <br>
```

When you run it, only one value appears on the server, instead of all values ​​in the color array.

How do I proceed to create and populate this array?

Comment: My first thought is: each time the user clicks the button, add a hidden input named `allColors[]`. There could be a better solution out there, but I don't see it right now

Comment: why not simply insert it into an empty array and than submit the value of this array to the php file ?

Answer (score 0):

you could simply create an empty array and then start pushing the value of your input inside this array

```
var arr= [];
var inp = document.getElementById("color");
function append(){
  arr.push(inp.value);
}
```

than on the submit event you send the value of this array to your php file

I made you an example on Codepen using your code , here is the link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gewabp

Comment: How do you send the value of this array to your php file? use AJAX?

Comment: yeah use a simple ajax request on the submit event